# Sony SBH50 SDK Control API

Tags: android, bluetooth, sony

I have an SBH50 from Sony this one, http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/accessories/stereo-bluetooth-headset-sbh50/, (not the MW1).

I've been wasting time trying to make work the sample control app which sony provides in the Add On SDK.

I was able to run the notification API example, it creates a new item in the 'Events list'. But I cant do the same with the Control API.

Btw, I cant either debug the app. I mean, I put a breakpoint in the same point a log is made, and the log IS made, but the debug does not stops there.

I just want to capture a key event.

Answer (score 1):

The Control API isn't supported on the SBH50, only the Notification API as you have noted above.

In order to debug try running your extension in debug mode, then in DDMS select the running task and press the debug button.  Then it should stop at your breakpoints.

Comment: Is there any other way I can capture a key press?  I am interesting in launch an action when the BACK key is pressed.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  What exactly are you trying to do in your app?

Comment: I want to make an app to read the time when the back button is pressed!

Comment: Sounds simple enough.  Without the Control API though I don't think it would be possible to do that.  The Control API is supported in the Smart Wireless Headset Pro but not the model that you have.

Comment: do you have any idea if its going to be supported on the future?

Comment: No plans for it to be supported, but will let you know if that changes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Sony has just released new add-on API to control the SBH50 as well. Please refer to link below:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/11/12/sony-add-on-sdk-updated-adds-support-for-stereo-bluetooth-headset-sbh50-and-smart-bluetooth-handset-sbh52/

Comment: Bad news, only the Notification API is supported. The Control API isnt supported yet.